# Why do graph plotting applications draw $\frac{1}{\tan x}$ the same as $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$?

Tags: graphing-functions, desmos

At $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x21edfvyaj) acts like they both have an intersection with the line $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, even though obviously the function $\frac{1}{\tan x}$ is undefined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Why is that?

Comment: It may be internally simplifying to $\cot x$ then plotting that.

Comment: It's likely that the function is not even evaluated at $\pi/2$, due to numerical precision in the representation of the $x$ axis points.

Comment: It is even more than likely that the program uses a (floating point) representation of real numbers that cannot exactly represent $\pi/2$, or any real number outside a certain finite set of rational numbers, at all, let alone evaluate functions at such a value.

Comment: Identifying the x-coordinates of holes in a graph is a difficult problem, and then identifying their corresponding y-coordinates is a difficult problem beyond that. What surprises me however is that evaluating $\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})}$ in the calculator gives $0$. Wolfram Alpha has this same error: <https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Ftan%28pi%2F2%29>

Comment: @TomKern Yeah, although "casio fx-991es plus" (real life calculator) seems to indeed give Math Error. Any clue why there are differences?

Comment: Having pulled apart a few parsers (but not Desmos' yet), my guess is that the error is happening at the parsing stage. Some parsers will try to simplify formulas while putting them together. KAS.js, for instance, automatically turns a/b into a*(b^-1). I suspect that wolfram alpha on the other hand is applying an algebraic simplification rule.

Answer (score 0):

In desmos, there are three types of "undefineds:"

1. Real undefined. This undefined is what we usually mean by the notion of infinity. Desmos has two "real infinities:" positive and negative.  However, as a whole, both the positive real and the negative real infinities correspond to the same type.
2. Imaginary undefined. This undefined represents pretty much everything besides the real infinities. The most common way to get them is by taking the square root of a negative number. However, there are many other ways, such as going over/under the index of a list.
3. Inequality undefined.  This undefined crops up when you use inequalities, namely restricting functions using curly brackets (`{` and `}`)

You con see how these three undefineds act in [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jvz9p6bgjx) graph.

When you plug in $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ into $\tan(x)$, you get the first infinity, the real infinity. And because the reciprocal of the real infinity is $0$, $\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$ is zero for $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and has nothing to do with $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$.